# How to measure "homogeneity" of time series?

Tags: algorithm, math, time-series, signal-processing

I have two time series, see this pic:
[image]

I need to measure the level of "homogeneity" of the series. So the first one looks very fragmented, so it should have low value close to zero and the second one should have a high value.

Any ideas of an algorithm I could use?

Comment: Have you tried cross correlating the two series?

Comment: I don't want to compare these two. I just want to measure the homogeneity as a stand-alone measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what is meant by homogeneity, but there is a well-established notion of stationarity of a time series. Basically, a time series is stationary if its rolling mean and standard deviation are constant across time. Both of your time series seem to have roughly constant mean, but the top one has a standard deviation that changes wildly across time; sometimes it's almost zero, and at other times, it's very large. Perhaps you could take the standard deviation of the rolling standard deviation, which will be far higher for the top series than for the bottom. If you can load them into pandas as top and bottom, it might look like

```
top_nonstationarity = np.std(top.rolling(window_size).std())
bottom_nonstationarity = np.std(bottom.rolling(window_size).std())
```

Answer (score 1):

It might help to know more about the underlying difference between the series, or what you care about, but here goes...

I would subtract constants, if required, to give both series mean zero, and then square them to get something resembling power and filter this enough to smooth away what seems to be noise in the case of the lower filter. Then compute and compare the variances of the two filtered powers, which for the lower time series I would now expect to be a fairly constant line with a few drops down and for the upper series something spending about half of its time near zero and about half of its time away from it.

Possible filters include a simple moving average, whatever your time series toolkit provides, and those described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter